# What memory is for the constants defined in a method?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

Someone I could describe what happens (from the perspective of memory management) when a constant is defined within a method in. Net?

Comment: At runtime they are stored in heap memory as they exist through out the execution and are not garbage collected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants are usually resolved at compile time and inserted into the instruction sequence directly. Example:

```
const int A = 10;
int b;

int i = A + b;
```

would effectively be compiled into:

```
int i = 10 + b;
```

For strings they are being interned and put on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces because there is no variable address associated with a constant at run time const fields cannot be passed by reference and cannot appear as an l-value in an expression. And for further information you can check [Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on Msdn.